# .setAttribute("disabled", false); changes editable attribute to false

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I want to have textboxes related to radiobuttons. Therefore each radio button should enable it's textbox and disable the others. However when I set the disabled attribute of textbox to true, it changes the editable attribute too. I tried setting editable attribute true again but it did not work.

This was what I tried:

JS function:

```
function enable(id)
{
    var eleman = document.getElementById(id);
    eleman.setAttribute("disabled", false);
    eleman.setAttribute("editable", true);
}
```

XUL elements:

```
<radio id="pno" label="123" onclick="enable('ad')" />
<textbox id="ad" editable="true"  disabled="true" flex="1" emptytext="asd" onkeypress="asd(event)" tooltiptext="" >
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

A `disabled` element is, (self-explaining) disabled and thereby logically not editable, so:

> set the disabled attribute [...] changes the editable attribute too

Is an intended and well-defined behaviour.

The real problem here seems to be you're trying to set `disabled` to `false` via `setAttribute()` which doesn't do what you're expecting. an element is disabled if the `disabled`-attribute is set, independent of it's value (so, `disabled="true"`, `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled="false"` all do the same: the element gets disabled). you should instead remove the complete attribute:

```
element.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

or set that property directly:

```
element.disabled = false;
```

Comment: Good answer, but in the latter case you say "set that attribute directly" and I believe it should be "set that property directly," since you are editing DOM property rather than HTML attribute.  Subtle difference but important here I think.

Comment: is there any way i can use `setAttribute()` to do the exact same thing? `setAttribute("disabled","true");` doesn't work;

Answer (score 18):

Just set the property directly: .

```
eleman.disabled = false;
```

Comment: is there any way i can use setAttribute() to do the exact same thing? setAttribute("disabled","true"); doesn't work

Comment: @AjayAradhya—see the accepted answer. The *disabled* attribute is boolean, its presence sets its value to true. The only way to fix that is to either set the property to false or remove the attribute using *removeAttribute*.

Answer (score 13):

Using method **set** and **remove** *attribute*

```js
function radioButton(o) {

  var text = document.querySelector("textarea");

  if (o.value == "on") {
    text.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
    text.setAttribute("enabled", "");
  } else {
    text.removeAttribute("enabled", "");
    text.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="on" onclick = "radioButton(this)" />Enable
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="off" onclick = "radioButton(this)" />Disabled<hr/>

<textarea disabled ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try doing this instead:

```
function enable(id)
{
    var eleman = document.getElementById(id);
    eleman.removeAttribute("disabled");        
}
```

To enable an element you have to remove the disabled attribute. Setting it to false still means it is disabled.

http://jsfiddle.net/SRK2c/

Answer (score 5):

the disabled attributes value is actally not considered.. usually if you have noticed the attribute is set as disabled="disabled" the "disabled" here is not necessary persay.. thus the best thing to do is to remove the attribute.

```
element.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

also you could do

```
element.disabled=false;
```

Answer (score 3):

just replace 'myselect' with your id

to disable->

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = true;
```

to enable->

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

An update in 2022.

There is another method [`toggleAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute) more specific to this use case if you don't need to consider IE11 and other legacy browsers.

```js
element.toggleAttribute("disabled");
```

switches between `<input value="text" disabled />` and `<input value="text" />`, and moreover,

```js
element.toggleAttribute("disabled", true);
```

sets `<input value="text" disabled />` explicitly, no matter what state the element was; similarly,

```js
element.toggleAttribute("disabled", false);
```

sets `<input value="text" />` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There you go,

```
<div immutable='id,class' id='abc' class='xyz'></div>
<h1 immutable='onclick' onclick='alert()'>HI</h1>
<p immutable='id' subtree>
   <!-- now childs id are immutable too -->
   <span id='xyz'>HELLO</span>
</p>

</script>
   const mutationHandler = entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.type !== 'attributes') return;
        mutationObserver.disconnect()
        entry.target.setAttribute(entry.attributeName, entry.oldValue)
        observe()
    })
}

const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationHandler)

const observe = () => {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('[immutable]');
    items.forEach(item => {
        let subtreeEnabled = item.getAttribute('subtree') != null

        let immutableAttr = item.getAttribute('immutable')
        let captureAttrs = immutableAttr.split(',');
        captureAttrs.push('immutable')
        captureAttrs.push('subtree')
        
        mutationObserver.observe(item, {
            subtree: subtreeEnabled,
            attributes: true,
            attributeOldValue: true,
            attributeFilter: captureAttrs
        })
    })
}
observe()
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.