# How do I change the minute with the spinbutton in XUL's timepicker element?

Tags: javascript, firefox, datetime, firefox-addon, xul

I can't seem to change the minutes with the spinbuttons. The spinbuttons only change the hours, and when you cycle through 12 hours, the AM/PM changes by itself. The wiki says I must select the minute textbox so the spinbuttons change minutes, but I can't select anything?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/timepicker
https://wiki.mozilla.org/XUL:Specs:DateTimePickers

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Simply put your mouse cursor in the minutes, and now the updown button is acting on minutes. Same for seconds and hours. Did you set some specific attributes or properties ? (if you set `increment` to 60 you may only see hours changing).

Comment: Thanks Yolanda for helping me pinpoint my problem. It seems my problem was due to the disabled attribute. Since the timepicker is really just 4 textboxes, the disabled attribute (true or false) disables edits to the timepicker.

Comment: In general in HTML the disabled attribute is just tested for presence, not value. A value of "true", "false" or "disabled" should result in disabling. Even in XUL, I would stick to disabled="true" or not including the attribute at all if it shouldn't be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the disabled attribute. Setting the attribute to false creates this strange behavior.

See

[.setAttribute("disabled", false); changes editable attribute to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526601/setattributedisabled-false-changes-editable-attribute-to-false)