# How do I change the color of a button depending on an if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a website that requires user registration.  On the register form, I have 4 text fields, and a "register" button.  I have a username field, email field, password field, and a confirm password field.  There are several tests that are executed whenever a user inputs information. For example, there is a username availability checker, an email validator, a password match checker, and a password strength checker.  In order for a user to be able to register, I want all of these tests to be passed.  If at least one of these tests fail, for example the user's passwords don't match, I don't want the register button to be clickable(and I'd also like the register button to be gray'd out while it's unclickable.)  Here's my attempt:

First, I set 4 variables. Each variable represents a test that was undergone.

```
var test1 = 0;
var test2 = 0;
var test3 = 0;
var test4 = 0;
```

By default, all tests are set to '0' which would represent a failed test. So by default, the register button should be unclickable and gray'd out.

Then, I edited the tests themselves. If the test was passed, I would set the corresponding test variable to '1'. For example, here's my username test:

```
if(msg == 'OK') //if the username is available
{ 

    $("#username").removeClass("red");
    $("#username").addClass("green");
    msgbox.html('<img src="available.png" align="absmiddle">');
    test1 = 1; //sets the first test variable as passed
}  
else  //if the username is not available
{  
     $("#username").removeClass("green");
     $("#username").addClass("red");
    msgbox.html(msg);
    test1 = 0; //sets the first test variable as failed
}
```

There is a lot more code used to make the username availability checker work, however I don't feel that the rest of the code is necessary to the question I have.

I then repeat that same idea throughout the other 3 tests. The email validator, the password strength checker, and the password match checker. If all 4 tests were passed(if all 4 text fields were filled out correctly) then all test variables are set to '1'.

Next, I set up a function that checks the value of the test variables to see whether or not they are passed.

```
function checkButton(){

if (test1 == 1 && test2 == 1 && test3 == 1 && test4 == 1){ //checks if all 4 tests are passed
$("#register").prop('disabled', false); //if they are, make the register button clickable
} else {
$("#register").prop('disabled', true); //if not, make the register button NOT clickable
$("#register").style.backgroundColor = "#A09B9B"; //as well as change the button background color to gray.
}
}
```

After that, I call the function every time a key is pressed in any of the fields.  I do this by using the 'onkeyup' attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="username" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'username'); checkButton()" id="username" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter your desired username"/><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" onkeyup="checkButton()" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail address here"/><br>
<input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" onkeyup="checkStrength(); checkPasswordMatch(); checkButton()" placeholder="Enter a password with more than 5 characters"/><br>
<input type="password" id="password2" onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch(); checkButton()" name="password2" placeholder="Enter the same password you entered above"/><br>
```

If seeing my register form in action would help, visit it here: [register form](http://registerform.sytes.net)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is "How to disable a submit button?", this code would help you.

This code to disable the submit button:

```
document.getElementById("register").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

And this to enable it:

```
document.getElementById("register").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Using `setAttribute("disabled", "false")` will not enable the submit button (more information here: [.setAttribute("disabled", false); changes editable attribute to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526601/setattributedisabled-false-changes-editable-attribute-to-false))

Hope this helps