# Button is not disabled via javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following button.

```
<input type="button" id="attractionsSection" value="Warsztaty" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddAttractions","ReservationDetails")'" disabled="disabled" />
```

In js script i check wheather some condition is true and then I set property disabled of button.

```
if(Model.stagesConfirmation[4]==true)
                                {
                                <script>
                                    $(function () {
                                        console.log('Test1');
                                        document.getElementById('attractionsSection').disabled = 'true';
                                        console.log(document.getElementById('attractionsSection'));
                                        console.log('Test2');
                                    });
                                </script>
                            }
```

I use console log to test wheather this condition is passed and that is OK. I set disabled and button still remains active. This console.log

```
console.log(document.getElementById('attractionsSection'));
```

shows me the following thing

```
<input type="button" id="attractionsSection" value="Warsztaty" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddAttractions","ReservationDetails")'"/>
```

So it is not disabled. How to solve, what can be the problem?

Comment: Do you see that output in your browser console?  E.g. "Test1", "Test2", etc?  Are you sure your button is rendered by the time any of that executes?

Comment: Yes Test1 and Test2 shows me in browser.

Comment: Okay, but are you enforcing that the page is rendered before your script runs? Doesn't look like it. And the button appears to be disabled by default, so how would you know if your script is disabling the button or not?  Look into various methods (jQuery and others) of waiting for the page to load before executing your script.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526601/setattributedisabled-false-changes-editable-attribute-to-false). You need to use `element.removeAttribute("disabled");` or `element.disabled = false;`

You don't say `disabled=true` you just say `disabled`. Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) for documentation on the `disabled` attribute.

You could say `disabled="foobar"` and it will still disable the button. To prove that, play around with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled).

Comment: On the same page I use document.getElementById('attractionsSection').disabled = 'true'; for other buttons  and it works fine and this buttons have the same structure.

Comment: Okay, relevant tryit here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_pushbutton_disabled2

I am not able to reproduce your issue here. What happens if you `console.log(document.getElementById('attractionsSection'));` *before* setting `disabled=true`?

Comment: Problem was in other place I have overriden attribute disabled of this button on false that;t why it didn't work. Thanks for advice.