# Disabled button event

Tags: pyscript

I'm trying to get a button disabled when I press another button, but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.11.1/core.css" />
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.11.1/core.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button  id="run" py-click="colorChange">NO CLICK</button>
        <button  id="run2" py-click="disabled">CLICK</button>

    </div>
    <style>
        #run{ background-color: rgb(61, 139, 130)}
        #run2{ background-color: rgb(179, 28, 65)}
    </style>
    <py-script>
        from js import document
        runButton=document.getElementById("run")
        def colorChange(event):
            runButton.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red")

        def disabled(event):
            runButton.setAttribute("style", "disabled:True")
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently setting a CSS rule called "disabled" to `True`. You want to be setting the attribute `disabled` to True:

```py
def disabled(event):
    runButton.setAttribute("disabled", True)
```

Related, when you want to re-enable that button, [use the `removeAttribute` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526601/setattributedisabled-false-changes-editable-attribute-to-false), instead of setting disabled to False.